# Laravel 4 How to return nothing

Tags: laravel-4, return

php:

```
if(form not filled out correctly){
     What do i do?
}
... create zip...
DownloadController::sendZipHeader($zip, $zip_name, $data_size);
```

If the form is filled out correctly, the page won't change.  The only thing that will happen is the download will start.

If form is filled out incorrectly, i'd still like the page not to change/redirect just like if a download occurred.

Calling exit; and returning null will bring the user to an empty page. (not what I want)

I'd like to know if there's a way to do this without ajax/redirecting back to the download page?

One work around I thought of would be to send an empty file or something but I'm curious if there's a cleaner work around.

Comment: I ended up just using Ajax, don't think there's any header magic which would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to show the form again just return the form view once more.

A better option though would be to redirect the user back to the form as it provides a more fluid user experience. You should also alert the user of the errors that were encountered and why the form could not be processed.

```
return Redirect::to('/download_form')->with('error', 'You did not fill out the form correctly.');
```

Then, in your download form view, you can output this error.

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
    {{ Session::get('error') }}
@endif
```